# Get servers hostname using Nagios

Tags: nagios

I am sure that this must be simple but can not seem to find out how.

I want to display in Nagios the hostname of the host that I have setup. It would be purely information but gives me a way to check that the machine set up in Nagios is called the same as the actual servers hostname.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write your own plugin that would take $HOSTNAME$ and compare it to the local `hostname` value, returning the appropriate nagios-friendly results.